# How to make hierarchy path from bottom SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm trying to make reverse hierarchy path.

This is for path manager-subordinate

```sql
WITH CTE_Path AS 
(
    SELECT 
        P1.EmployeeID, P1.ManagerID, 
        CAST(FirstName + LastName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS PathHierarchy, 
        1 AS level
    FROM 
        EmployeesManagers AS P1
    WHERE 
        ManagerID IS NULL
 
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT 
        P2.EmployeeID, P2.ManagerID, 
        CONCAT(CAST(C.PathHierarchy AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),  N' > ', 
        CAST(P2.FirstName+LastName AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), level + 1 
    FROM 
        EmployeesManagers AS P2
    JOIN 
        CTE_Path AS C ON C.EmployeeID = P2.ManagerID 
)
SELECT PathHierarchy
FROM CTE_Path
```

Data for this

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmployeesManagers
(
    EmployeeID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ManagerID int NULL
)
GO

INSERT INTO EmployeesManagers VALUES (101, 'Ken', 'SÃ¡nchez', NULL)
INSERT INTO EmployeesManagers VALUES (102, 'Terri', 'Duffy', 101)
INSERT INTO EmployeesManagers VALUES (103, 'Roberto', 'Tamburello', 101)
INSERT INTO EmployeesManagers VALUES (104, 'Rob', 'Walters', 102)
INSERT INTO EmployeesManagers VALUES (105, 'Gail', 'Erickson', 102)
INSERT INTO EmployeesManagers VALUES (106, 'Jossef', 'Goldberg', 103)
INSERT INTO EmployeesManagers VALUES (107, 'Dylan', 'Miller', 103)
INSERT INTO EmployeesManagers VALUES (108, 'Diane', 'Margheim', 105)
INSERT INTO EmployeesManagers VALUES (109, 'Gigi', 'Matthew', 105)
INSERT INTO EmployeesManagers VALUES (110, 'Michael', 'Raheem', 106)
```

And I need subordinate-manager-manager1 - ...

What to change here? Anchor or recursive part?

Is it possible to create function where you can give argument EmployeeID and it will return path employee-manager-manager1-ceoOfCompany?

Comment: For the sample data you've provided, what are your expected results? What about what you have isn't working (as you expect)?

Comment: I got path ceo-manager-subordinate. But what should I change to get cte not from parentID to childID but in reverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse the logic by starting where employees are not a manager and then tweak the join in the second part of the recursive subquery:

```
WITH CTE AS (
      SELECT P1.EmployeeID, P1.ManagerID, CAST(FirstName+LastName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS PathHierarchy, 1 as level
      FROM EmployeesManagers AS P1
      WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM EmployeesManagers em2 WHERE EM2.ManagerID = p1.EmployeeId)
      UNION ALL
      SELECT P2.EmployeeID, P2.ManagerID, CONCAT(CAST(C.PathHierarchy AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),  N' > ', CAST(P2.FirstName+LastName AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), level+1 
      FROM CTE c JOIN
           EmployeesManagers P2
           ON P2.EmployeeID = C.ManagerID 
    )
SELECT PathHierarchy
FROM CTE;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1be8a7851e1fde8438429038d0b3c48f) is a db<>fiddle.